# Возвращение текста

Tags: java, android

Есть класс `Quote`. В нём метод:

```
public String getQuote(int key) {
     String quote = "";
     switch(key) {
          case 0: quote = "Q1"; break;
          case 1: quote = "Q2"; break;
          case 2: quote = "Q3"; break;
          default: qoute = "Error"; break;
     }
     return qoute;
}
```

Потом пытаюсь этот текст назначить TextView:

```
Qoute qoute = new Quote();
textViewQuote.setText(qoute.getQoute(0));
```

Когда запускаю приложение, появляется ошибка `java.lang.NullPointerException`, и указывает на строку:

```
textViewQuote.setText(quote.getQuote(0));
```

Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Вы пытались воспользоваться отладчиком? Полагаю, что `textViewQuote` по какой-то причине равен `null`. Где вы инициализируете этот объект?

Comment: textViewQuote - как объявляется и инициируется этот объект? Ну т.е. если null не qoute, то textViewQuote.

Comment: @iksuy
@Mark
Вот инициализация: `textViewQuote = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quote);`. Инициализирую сразу перед использованием

Comment: Так а с отладкой что? Вы доолжны воспользоваться отладчиком, увидеть какой объект во время выполнения этой строки равен `null`, затем понять почему он равен `null`. В документации сказано, что `findViewById` может возвращать `null` :  `The view that has the given id in the hierarchy or null `. Видимо он вам и возвращает `null` по какой-то причине.